# Django creates all model tables in both databases

Tags: python, django, database

I made two databases in my django project, one app writes it's data to one database, second - to other. But when I make migration, all models from both apps create their tables in both databases, though they still remain empty (just one null row in every table)

Is it possible to tell Django (Django, don't do it=) not to create extra tables which I don't need in both databases?

Here is my code

**routers.py**

```
    from django.conf import settings

class DatabaseAppsRouter(object):

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """"Point all read operations to the specific database."""
    if model._meta.app_label in settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING:
        return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING[model._meta.app_label]
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """Point all write operations to the specific database."""
    if model._meta.app_label in settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING:
        return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING[model._meta.app_label]
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """Allow any relation between apps that use the same database."""
    db_obj1 = settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(obj1._meta.app_label)
    db_obj2 = settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(obj2._meta.app_label)
    if db_obj1 and db_obj2:
        if db_obj1 == db_obj2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return None

def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
    """Make sure that apps only appear in the related database."""
    if db in settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.values():
        return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(model._meta.app_label) == db
    elif model._meta.app_label in settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING:
        return False
    return None
```

**settings.py**

```
    DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),

},
'tracking_db': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
     'NAME': 'tracking',
     'USER': 'root',
     'PASSWORD': '12345678',
}
}

 DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {
'contenttypes': 'default',
'auth': 'default',
'admin': 'default',
'sessions': 'default',
'messages': 'default',
'staticfiles': 'default',
'news': 'default',

'tracking': 'tracking_db',
 }
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['newswallproj.routers.DatabaseAppsRouter']
```

**models.py**

```
Model here
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'tracking'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, this is just how the migrations system currently works. There's an [open issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23273) about this that you might find helpful.

As noted in comment 6, a possible partial workaround is to specify the app when you do the migrations:

```
./manage.py migrate inapppurchase --database=iap
./manage.py migrate myapp --database=default
```

That's definitely not a robust solution, though.

Comment: The bad thing here is that this problem is not written anywhere, just in their ticket.
Anyway, it's better than nothing