# django single app multiple dbs: same tables get created in all dbs

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am test-developing a django project with a single app (app_name) where I want to have 2 models (say: `model_A` and `model_B`), with their instances stored in separate DBs (say: `DB_A.sqlite3`, `DB_B.sqlite3`). I also have third DB (`DB_users.sqlite3`) for storing anything related to auth, sessions etc.

I am trying to implement multiple dbs as per django documentation, with database routing etc., but I noticed at migrations that in each of those 3 DBs irrelevant tables get created for both models. For example, `DB_A` would have `my_app_model_A` as well as `my_app_model_B` table created. But the thing is `my_app_model_B` should only be stored in `DB_B`.

What can be the reason for this / how to ensure that only relevant tables get created in correct DBs?

=== EDIT===

Let me add the code indeed as this will make it easier to review. For simplicity, I am scaling down to a single `Document` model in `docs` sqlite DB, and a separate `auth` sqlite DB for user info, sessions etc. Django project name is `docs_rev`, django app name is `reviewer`. When I create document or a user, instances land in correct tables in correct DBs, however the problem I see is that both DBs have the same set of tables, which is strange IMHO. E.g. `docs` db has also all the `auth*` tables (although empty), and  `auth` db has the `reviewer_document` table (although empty).

My code:
**docs_rev\docs_rev\settings.py**

```py
...

DATABASES = {
    
    'default':{},

    'auth': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'auth.sqlite3'),
    },

    'docs' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'docs.sqlite3'),
    },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'reviewer.router.authRouter',
    'reviewer.router.docsRouter', 
]

...
```

**docs_rev\docs_rev\urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('reviewer/', include ('reviewer.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='reviewer/', permanent=True)),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

**docs_rev\reviewer\urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('docs/', views.DocsListView.as_view(), name='docs'),
    path('doc/<uuid:pk>', views.DocDetailView.as_view(), name='document-detail'),
]
```

**docs_rev\reviewer\models.py**

```py
...
class Document(models.Model):

...
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'reviewer'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('document-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**docs_rev\reviewer\router.py**

```py
class authRouter:
    route_app_labels = {'admin', 'auth', 'contenttypes', 'flatpages', 'redirects', 'sessions', 'sites'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'auth'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'auth'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return True
        return None

class docsRouter(object): 

    route_app_labels = {'reviewer'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'docs'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'docs'
        return None
    
    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or \
           obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:       
            return True
        return None
    
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return True
        return None
```

Comment: You aren't showing us code, so this is only a guess: are you appropriately using `using()` to scope your queries to the appropriate DB? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.using

Comment: It looks like a duplicate to the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289210/django-creates-all-model-tables-in-both-databases

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the database router is the `route_app_labels`
This ensures those apps always use the specified DB.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/

```
class AuthRouter:
    route_app_labels = {'auth', 'contenttypes'}
    ...rest of router code...
```

Also, double check that the `DATABASE_ROUTERS` in settings.py is correct.

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.AuthRouter', 'path.to.PrimaryReplicaRouter']
```